# ASPX Form messing up Bootstrap styles

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have no background in ASPX, but have been assigned to restyle an application that is being built. I decided to use bootstrap, but am having one major issue. I have tracked down the problem to the first `<form id="Form1" runat="server">` in the `<body>` on my Site.Master, which from what I understand is how ASPX treats everything, like a form.

This ASPX form tag is keeping all the labels in other forms to their own line, and all preceding elements to the next line.

Some problematic code, when ran inside of the form tag that ASPX requires to wrap everything:

```
<form class="form-horizontal span6">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
           <label class="control-label" for="tbUsername">Username</label>
           <div class="controls">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" placeholder="Password" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
           </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Thanks much Stack!

Comment: Try clearing all styles on the form and putting a container inside of it. I used to have lots of issues with this back when I did webforms and usually resorted to using a style reset on the form tag and using other elements above/below to style.

Comment: Trying putting a reset on the aspx form tag? then wrap the rest of everything in a container?